# gulp serve unhandled error

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, yeoman

So my friend made repository on github.
We are using yeoman.
So I clone it on my PC and follow instructions from https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp .
The problem starts when I use gulp serve and I get the following error:

```
$ gulp serve
[10:00:33] Using gulpfile D:\Projekti programiranje\PracticeBand\gulpfile.js
[10:00:33] Starting 'serve'...
[10:00:33] Starting 'clean'...
[10:00:33] Starting 'wiredep'...
[10:00:33] Finished 'wiredep' after 18 ms
[10:00:33] Finished 'serve' after 27 ms
[10:00:33] Finished 'clean' after 32 ms
[10:00:33] Starting 'styles'...
[10:00:34] Starting 'scripts'...
[10:00:34] Starting 'fonts'...
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object.
at fromObject (buffer.js:262:9)
at Function.Buffer.from (buffer.js:101:10)
at new Buffer (buffer.js:80:17)
at DestroyableTransform._transform (D:\Projekti programiranje\PracticeBand\node_modules\wiredep\wiredep.js:136:23)
at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (D:\Projekti programiranje\PracticeBand\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:159:10)
at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (D:\Projekti programiranje\PracticeBand\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:147:83)
at doWrite (D:\Projekti programiranje\PracticeBand\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:313:64)
at writeOrBuffer (D:\Projekti programiranje\PracticeBand\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:302:5)
at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (D:\Projekti programiranje\PracticeBand\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:241:11)
at write (D:\Projekti programiranje\PracticeBand\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:623:24)
```

Please help with this problem.

Comment: did you solve this? what was it?

Comment: @sscarduzio npm install gulp-filter --save-dev
Add the following code between this two lines: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/blob/master/app/templates/gulpfile.js#L179-L180

.pipe($.filter(function(a){ return a.stat && a.stat.size }))

Comment: check your index.html whether it has data or it is empty